# reference to virtual function

Tags: c++, reference, undefined

Supose i have a base class A and derived classes B and C.
I wish to be able to execute a method of a derived function via a pointer of reference of type A.
I've tried using virtual functions:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual std::string a() { return "a() of a"; }
    virtual std::string b();
    virtual std::string c();
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    std::string a() { return "a() of b"; }
    std::string b() { return "b() of b"; }
};

class C : public A
{
public:
    std::string a() { return "a() of c"; }
    std::string c() { return "c() of c"; }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    B b;
    C c;

    A* a1 = &b;
    A* a2 = &c;

    std::cout << a1->b() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a2->c() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But i keep getting this:

> /tmp/ccsCMwc6.o:(.rodata._ZTV1C[_ZTV1C]+0x18): undefined reference to
>   `A::b()' /tmp/ccsCMwc6.o:(.rodata._ZTV1B[_ZTV1B]+0x20): undefined
>   reference to`A::c()' /tmp/ccsCMwc6.o:(.rodata._ZTI1C[_ZTI1C]+0x10):
>   undefined reference to `typeinfo for A'
>   /tmp/ccsCMwc6.o:(.rodata._ZTI1B[_ZTI1B]+0x10): undefined reference to`
>   typeinfo for A'

Help?

Comment: Don't forget virtual destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler will generate a virtual function table (vtbl) for each class, that points to the implementation of all the virtual functions of that class, for class A, it expects to find the implementations of A::b() and A::c().

If you do not want to implement them, you need to declare them as pure virtual:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual std::string a() { return "a() of a"; }
    virtual std::string b() = 0;
    virtual std::string c() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

All virtual functions need to have a definition (implementation).

Comment: But what if A does not use this functions? Is there any keyword that can prevent writing defenitions?  And what if the return type of b() and c() is string - is there any string-default return value ?

Comment: @AlexGoft Making them *abstract* possibly? But then the function have to be defined by the derived classes.

Answer (score 0):

Looks OK to me. You don't need to have definitions in the base class if you only instantiate an inherited class.

What compiler is it?

Comment: g++ -std=c++11 -Wextra -Wall